# setting width with calc() in [ngStyle] with angular(not js) variable not working

Tags: html, angular, angular8, ng-style

This is Angular 8 related question. not angular JS where declarations/syntax is different.

I am setting width of a div dynamically via angular variable. Here is my template looks like:

```
<nav class="navbar-dark" 
[ngClass]="isDefault() ? 'navbar-original': 'navbar'"
[ngStyle]="{ 'margin-left.px': navbarMargin, 'width.px': 'calc(100% - ' + navbarMargin + 'px)' }">
```

In here, margin-left is working fine but width is not updating.

Tried

```
[style.width.%]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('calc(100% - 80px)')"
```

and

```
[ngStyle]="{'width.px': width}"
```

and various combinations of these. Nothing is updating width.

What exactly I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply using [style.width]? "calc(100%- 80px)" is a string after all and [style.width.px] expects a number.